# MongoDB Timeseries unusably slow queries after deletion and re-creation

Tags: mongodb

My measurements:

I have 3 `measurement` types, a lot of `asset`s, and `data` with `timestamp`s. The size of the timeseries grows by ~5GB / month after compression.

My timeseries collections:

I had a blank timeseries DB initially. It was slow so I indexed it, it became actually extremely fast and handy to use. After a few months, it became too large. I couldn't delete old entries in time, so I had to drop it. It became unusable.

I have created a new one, with *automatic deletion*. I indexed it in 2 ways.

```
.createIndex({measurement:1, asset:1})
```

```
.createIndex({asset:1, measurement:1, timestamp:1})
```

Each and every query for a *single asset's measurement type, limited to 1000* takes upwards of **2 minutes, if it ever returns at all**.

Example:

`{asset:"my_asset", measurement:"price"}`

`{measurement:"price", asset:"my_asset"}`

The database is unusable on arrival. It was never as functional, from the very start, with or without indexing the queries were unbearably slow.

The fastest query, which sometimes returns something, I found in MongoDB Compass. Using the indexes, just querying `{asset:"my_asset"}` with all the types and without limits, seems to be faster than querying into literally the easiest index to navigate, I don't know how on earth there could be a better index and how any query can take longer than a second. Literally, having it indexed by measurement type cuts off 66% of bilions of other entries initially, then asset: narrows down the asset and how can this take longer than a second?